# Sending an intent without a string first parameter

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to send an `intent` to a second activity without filling out the first `string` parameter in `intent.putExtra(String,var type)` ?

Right now I have this:

```
intent.putExtra("Average Score: ", averageScoreToSend);
```

I don't want to send the string if I don't have to, but if I have to then I'll just deal with it.

Also how do I pull the `double` value from the sent `intent`? I don't understand what value goes in the second parameter

```
Intent i;
double averageScore = 0;

i = getIntent();
averageScore = i.getDoubleExtra(Grade1.FINALMATHGRADE, IDK);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't need to send the string at all if I don't have to

Yes, you do. The extras are a key-value store, and the first parameter is the key. You need the key to look up the value later on.

> Also how do I pull the double value from the sent intent?

Call the appropriate `get...Extra()` method, passing in the key as the first parameter and the default value as the second parameter. The default value will be used in case the `Intent` does not contain an extra under the designated key.

Comment: Just to add, the `key` is no more than that...just a lookup. So using something like `"Average Score: "` is a little more complicated than it needs to be, IMHO. I would rather use something like `"avgScore"`. No need for the formatting, spaces, etc.

Comment: I meant to say `want` not `need`.. terrible grammer I apologize. But thank you, I got it now, I wasn't aware that it was a `key`, I understood it differently, but thanks :)